# In vulkan: I want save a depth image to file, but always got a error depth image

Tags: vulkan

I want to save a depth image that from frame buffer render result.

1, I create a stage buffer used to save image data.

2, use vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer copy depth image to stage buffer.

3, use vkMapMemory map this stage buffer memory to host memory.

4, read host memory and write depth data to a file.

but always got an error depth image. I don't know where have wrong.

application window [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbo7Z.png).

bug depth image [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFW45.png).

(source [file](https://pastebin.com/WbxQBjpu))

save depth image function:

```
VkDeviceSize size = WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4;
    VkBuffer dstBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory dstMemory;

    createBuffer(
        size,
        VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, 
        VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, 
        dstBuffer,
        dstMemory);

    VkCommandBuffer copyCmd = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    // depth format -> VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT
    VkBufferImageCopy region = {};
    region.bufferOffset = 0;
    region.bufferImageHeight = 0;
    region.bufferRowLength = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
    region.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    region.imageOffset = VkOffset3D{ 0, 0, 0 };
    region.imageExtent = VkExtent3D{ swapChainExtent.width, swapChainExtent.height, 1};


    vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(
        copyCmd,
        depthImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
        dstBuffer,
        1,
        &region
    );

    endSingleTimeCommands(copyCmd);


    // Map image memory so we can start copying from it
    void *data;
    vkMapMemory(device, dstMemory, 0, size, 0, &data);


    std::ofstream file(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    // ppm header
    file << "P6\n" << WIDTH << "\n" << HEIGHT << "\n" << 255 << "\n";

    float *row = (float*)data;

    auto size_v = WIDTH * HEIGHT;

    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < size_v; y++) {

        file.write((char*)row + 1, 1);
        file.write((char*)row + 1, 1);
        file.write((char*)row + 1, 1);

        row++;

    }

    file.close();

    // Clean up resources
    vkUnmapMemory(device, dstMemory);
    vkFreeMemory(device, dstMemory, nullptr);
    vkDestroyBuffer(device, dstBuffer, nullptr);
```

hope someone drag me out. thanks!

Comment: Do You perform proper layout transitions on the source image?

Comment: my source image(depth image) VkAttachmentDescription set initialLayout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, finalLayout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,  image usage is VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT. i have been check many times code, still don't find where have problem.!!!!

Comment: my depth format use VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT.

Comment: Could You also show the output of Your application (the screenshot of a scene You want to save depth buffer of)?

Comment: yes, I have been added application screenshot and my save depth image and source code file to this question in begin.

Comment: How do You know the depth output is incorrect? Sphere looks to be roughly the same size and position. These several gradients look like a float values interpreted as uints. And the white spot on the sphere looks either like a specific float value interpreted as a white uint, or like a depth values being clamped by a depth test setup. Try converting float values to uint colors (this can be done on the CPU side after You read the data from the buffer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've done all the transfer work correctly, your mapped data is basically an array of floats.  This is reflected in your code by this line:

`float *row = (float*)data;`

However, when you actually write out the file you're treating the data like bytes...

`file.write((char*)row + 1, 1);`

So you're writing out 8 bytes of a 32 bit float.  What you need is some function to convert from the float to a color value.

Assuming the depth value is normalized (I can't remember off the top of my head whether this is the case, or if it's dependent on the pipeline or framebuffer setup) and if you just want greyscale, you could use

```
uint8_t map(float f) {
  return (uint8_t)(f * 255.0f);
}
```

and inside your file writing loop you'd so something like

```
uint8_t grey = map(*row);
file.write(&grey, 1);
file.write(&grey, 1);
file.write(&grey, 1);
++row;
```

Alternatively if you want some sort of color gradient for easier visulization you'd want a more complex mapping function...

```
vec3 colorWheel(float normalizedHue) {
    float v = normalizedHue * 6.f;
    if (v < 0.f) {
        return vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    } else if (v < 1.f) {
        return vec3(1.f, v, 0.f);
    } else if (v < 2.f) {
        return vec3(1.f - (v-1.f), 1.f, 0.f);
    } else if (v < 3.f) {
        return vec3(0.f, 1.f, (v-2.f));
    } else if (v < 4.f) {
        return vec3(0.f, 1.f - (v-3.f), 1.f );
    } else if (v < 5.f) {
        return vec3((v-4.f), 0.f, 1.f );
    } else if (v < 6.f) {
        return vec3(1.f, 0.f, 1.f - (v-5.f));
    } else {
        return vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    }
}
```

and in your file output loop...

```
vec3 color = colorWheel(*row);
uint8_t r = map(color.r);
uint8_t g = map(color.g);
uint8_t b = map(color.b);
file.write(&r, 1);
file.write(&g, 1);
file.write(&b, 1);
++row;
```

Comment: I have been got my want result. thank you very much. :)